# Change button page link to a url

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like the change this code to redirect to a url google.com. How can I do this please?

```
echo '<a href="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '">' . __( 'Home' ) . '</a>';
```

Full code below:

```
add_filter( 'storefront_handheld_footer_bar_links', 'jk_add_home_link' );
function jk_add_home_link( $links ) {
    $new_links = array(
        'home' => array(
            'priority' => 10,
            'callback' => 'jk_home_link',
        ),
    );

    $links = array_merge( $new_links, $links );

    return $links;
}

function jk_home_link() {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '">' . __( 'Home' ) . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Really?  `echo '<a href="http://google.com">' . __( 'Go to Google' ) . '</a>';`